# I wrote a simple spring MVC program using maven which is throwing 404 error when i click the login button to redirect

Tags: maven, spring-mvc

[image: enter link description here]
Jul 18, 2017 8:45:43 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/hello-servlet.xml] Jul 18, 2017 8:45:44 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet initServletBean INFO: FrameworkServlet 'hello': initialization completed in 580 ms Jul 18, 2017 8:45:44 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound noHandlerFound WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/HelloWorld/faisal] in DispatcherServlet with name 'hello'

[image]

*hello-servlet.xml*

Answer (score 0):

you need to load `ApplicationContext.xml` in `web.xml` file, you can use sample bellow code for adding `ApplicationContext.xml` in web.xml

```
<servlet>
        <servlet-name>myServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>classpath:ApplicationContext.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
```

Comment: can you please elaborate more on this as I am new to learn mvc springs

Comment: refer this link : http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1245203&seqNum=3 for know more about ApplicationContext.xml.

Comment: Thanks Sharma let me read the link with maven it seems simplified let me try this also

Comment: ok.... you can try this.... and if you get some error then please share with me... thanks

Answer (score 0):

First if you want to get any response from your controller with your method declared as **VOID** you don't go to get any response, your method is printing in console the string faisl. Then if you want to get the index page that prints "faisal" you need to declare the controller like this:

```
@Controller
public class MainClass {

    @RequestMapping(value="/faisal", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView getIndex(){
        return new ModelAndView("index", "msg", "Hello Faisal");
    }

}
```

in your **hello-servlet.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns = "http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:ctx = "http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xmlns:xsi = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:mvc = "http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
   xsi:schemaLocation = "http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-2.5.xsd">

   <ctx:component-scan base-package="com.faisal"></ctx:component-scan>

   <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
      <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/" />
      <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
   </bean>

</beans>
```

now the **InternalViewResolver** is looking for your `index.jsp` view that you have declared under **/WEB-INF/**

In your `index.jsp` you can do the next to print the message that you has mapped to your view:

```
<body>
    <h1>${msg}</h1>
</body>
```

`${msg}` is the key that you are passing in the controller the value is `Hello faisal` then if you open the url

> /HelloWorld/faisal

in your view you should be able to see **Hello Faisal**

Regards,

Comment: I can able see the index.jsp. when redirect using the form or directly I pass HelloWorld/faisal, I am getting 404 and in eclipse, i can see the error as ,
org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound noHandlerFound

Comment: Can you explain a little bit more?, you are telling me that you are able to see index.jsp. What are you trying to do?